# Free text editor with subversion/source control support on mac

Tags: svn, macos, text-editor

Is there any? Right now i am using netbeans for this! Just to write some notes.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you didn't want to hear this, yet [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) can be configured to use subversion, and is free. If you decide to dive into that, maybe [aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) is something you'd like, its a mac-flavored emacs.

Comment: aquamacs has cvs support out of the box?

Comment: Emacs can out of the box use multiple version control backends with the same keybindings. Also, I'd recommend http://emacsformacosx.com/ rather than Aquamacs. I'm not a user of OSX myself but most Mac/Emacs fans I've talked to don't think highly of Aquamacs.

Comment: you're right there, i don't use aquamacs myself, but the "common look" may attract new users..

Answer (score 0):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is a great editor that supports Subversion however it is not free.

There is a 30 day free trial. It might do the job temporarily?

The 30 day trial works out as 30 days of using the program as a opposed to 30 days after you install it.

Comment: whats meant by "temporarily"?

Comment: You can use it for free for 30 days until you can find a better solution or possibly purchase the program.

Answer (score 0):

See [Good & Free Editor in Mac OS with highlighting and side-by-side editing/comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963289/good-free-editor-in-mac-os-with-highlighting-and-side-by-side-editing-compariso)

Xcode, Eclipse, Macvim, aquaemacs, and TextMate (not free, but worth the price if you like it) are pretty standard.

Comment: Xcode and Eclipse are great but since i just have to write notes i was looking for something light weight like TextMate but free.